# Can't use get_result(), mysqlnd is enabled

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just moved all of my website files and databases over to a webhost and I've run into the following error when trying to run one of my pages:

```
Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()
```

I saw this problem before and it had something to do with the mysqlnd driver not being installed. So I contacted the web host and they said that both mysqli and mysqlnd were installed by using the following PHP:

```
<?php
    if (extension_loaded('mysqlnd'))
        echo 'extension mysqlnd is loaded'; // WORKED

    if (extension_loaded('mysqli'))
        echo 'extension mysqli is loaded'; // WORKED
?>
```

And here's the PHP I'm trying to run:

```
<?php
    $cxn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_username", "my_password", "my_database") or die ("Couldn't connect to the server. Please try again.");

    $id = 0;

    $stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT value FROM test WHERE id = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    echo $result->num_rows;  
?>
```

Please help!

Comment: [The manual](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) also mentions PHP/5.3.0. What's yours?

Comment: I'm using version 5.4.24.

Comment: Save for error checking (which I guess was removed for brevity) your code looks just fine to me. It's normally easier to diagnose stuff with [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo) (if only because it shows way more info) but I can't think of a reason why `extension_loaded('mysqlnd')` would lie. Weird...

Answer (score 2):

mysqlnd is not actually an extension, but a library used to by extensions. So your host have to build php with options like `--with-mysqli=mysqlnd`

Comment: Did not get you. I am using a shared server. Could you please elaborate on this.